# Transfer files from Mediafire to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a few gigs stored at Mediafire and want to move them over to my S3 account.  Is there a straight forward way to basically "Upload from web" using a link to the file rather than downloading the files and then re-uploading them to the s3 servers?

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you only have a few gigs, using one of the many S3 browsers (e.g. [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/), [Cloudberry](http://cloudberrylab.com/)) will likely be the path of least resistance after you download the files from Mediafire.

You might save some time and money by booting up an EC2 instance -- you would only have to pay for the inbound data transfer and the pipe will be much larger.

Comment: +1 for EC2. A few gigs could be transferred in a matter of minutes, so you could easily get away with only being charged for 1 hour.